# TypeScript - How to infer the third tuple element's type based on pervious two

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function, where the second parameter is an `array` of `tuple`, where in each `tuple` the first element is the key of an object from generic, and second element is the key of a fixed-type object, say `Customer`, where the third element (the one I want to infer the type from the previous two) is a callback, taking value of `T[firstEl]` as type and expect to return a value of `Customer[secondEl]` type.

[TS playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&ts=5.1.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbaZAbwChlkQ4CAuZbKUAc2QB8L0AbDgbjOTxwAjYBwi16TVuy69yjCCAAm0cWAYhmbEJx58481es3TdAXxIlQkWIhQAFOAE8OOOIoCCxPgOGiA+gAOABY4IGJ0akyyyPrh2niC0CTmluDQ8EjIDs6uigBCXuQwwFDYfpQ0EUbR8koqVVHJFgih2MgIUBBwkACy6GDdEAAi3XDIALzIADwAKsgQAB6QSpjIAEoQLVCKUxIaADQxII4AfCcAFHwIWLgEUCMDtBjY+ND73nABAUyYtOcA2gBrCCOHAwZAzQ7A0Hg563N7Ic4ANzgHHQ4TgxwAlBMTkdHABdKRAkFgiFQ0mwm6vKAErH-AkkHHjE58c4BJwuNy0BxQMDAVGzE5Yp7Uu64wrkdqtMAUCAAdzhNIecFFL3FkyIyAAdLrruroCrkKZeHxyHhPt8NJhtTAcFAAKKIILnc4WgLMvGkKVS4Dgt2fbWiDRgIITcaTABMOO9PqlLRAbX+HJybgA0iDDvr4VAM4SJvxPtE48gzXGwoqxYbRv9szS80TJimuYpk5zcg3kAB+LvtKv3Gt1u4NsvkFIlv2I91BhSMUPhyYAZhjo-jMuQbdTijzWf7O+QakxmDtUDwjcLAVNJfIFaVdxVtb3IPPzdym5bI+vUt7h8TJ7w7Ltm474ds+WKrj6tBDtWAyPgaubPqu5g+qYWLcOQFg+p0YDoFAIBypW8Eqnw47SomsrQQOjxoP2BZahUcQ6IcPgiIxXCHLUyhQLQ2jsTEBgmMapoJm0eD9IMKqeJMHRdL04mQCqUzZC27gXFc-Yqu85D-GW-wAOQsf4wShBAemHAZQisXpBKHAA9LZFA4AeUBHv+yAwOgIAIPyoTIEE0AQIcmBOQAVjcdDAHgAQcI4MSYJgwCMPhoYoCiaIQGW9nIAAksg8qYrKKXtKiHCCIggIHk5iRkfQcCgBAiiVcgAAGyKouiPHoAk0Ceg0GjNZlDmgNgXSNWSrVpR1+K9ZijgDT6+mxGZyB6UthyTSgLItQAJEQG2mM1RJZWAjgBBA42xM1yDAKsCZItAkCNbgfWMHwjJoRYx2ned4LNZd123aE918g1TV7MwmKNc1hkQIEIRhFdN0XmdT1OdDlmiANWVajDtB6QAjJGi7LbEeORgADMtDGdXxnH1LxHDGiQIk4KIQY4IwbrycMozuOcOMY7DxlhHjhPE4cpPIBTxpYh9zPrmJAwKaMBTSZ0gx9ErPMDEpQH5Gp5CUZpfA6QtenFKUYDlFQpnmQx1nIMdLl-vaeDuZ53nAL5-mdEFoXhQlUUxXFCVJQe-nIBtb1MqaWXNRbZQMYjqzuijTXNUnEtKC1dNQFdnQWsNgkJV5KDAGAekpzdJfMKA4coK+bgkNjFA23jMwQNgJMCQzzGCzTHAcQoXED0zLNsy4nOKxJKv8+5JSJ23K0d13MtoUAA)

Object shapes looks like this:

```
interface Customer {
  name: string | null;
  mobile: string | null;
  gender: string | null;
  age: string | null;
}

interface PayloadA {
  mobile_phone: string;
  age: number
}

interface PayloadB {
  first_name: string;
  gender: string;
}
```

Function looks liks this:

where I want to infer the parameter type and return type of the callback instead of using `any`, based on the value given on first and second elements in the `tuple`

```
const createMutateData = <T extends Record<string, any>>(
  customerData: Customer,
  mappings: ([keyof T, keyof Customer, (value: any) => any] | [keyof T, keyof Customer])[]
) =>
  (payload: Partial<T>): Customer => {
    const newCustomerData: Customer = { ...customerData };

    mappings.forEach((map) => {
      if (map.length === 2) {
        const [payloadKey, customerKey] = map;
        
        newCustomerData[customerKey] = payload[payloadKey] ?? customerData[customerKey]
      }

      if (map.length === 3) {
        const [payloadKey, customerKey, transform] = map;

        newCustomerData[customerKey] = payload[payloadKey]
          ? transform(payload[payloadKey])
          : customerData[customerKey]
      }
    });  

    return newCustomerData
  }
```

Example usage:

```
const customerData: Customer = { name: null, mobile: null, gender: null, age: null };

const mutateDataA = createMutateData<PayloadA>(
  customerData,
  [
    ['mobile_phone', 'mobile'], // no transform function here, so just simply assign the value
    // I want the callback to be constrained to `(value: number) => string`
    // instead of `(value: any) => any`
    ['age', 'age', value => `${value}`] // typeof `age` is converted to string
  ]
);

// typeof `age` is converted to string and `mobile_phone` is mapped to `mobile`
// { mobile: '123', age: '20', name: null, gender: null }
mutateDataA({ mobile_phone: '123', age: 20 })

const mutateDataB = createMutateData<PayloadB>(
  customerData,
  [
    ['first_name', 'name'] // transform function here, so just simply assign the value
  ]
);

// `first_name` is mapped to `name`, and `gender` remains null since it's missing in the payload
// { name: 'Test', age: null, mobile: null, gender: null }
mutateDataB({ first_name: 'Test' });
```

constrained the callback to something like `(value: number) => string` instead of `(value: any) => any` based on given value for first and second element in `tuple` as described above

Comment: Will something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn86kW) work for you? It still shows `value: any`, however if you assign the wrong type to `value` manually, TS will fire an error. This is the limitation of typescript with tuples. If that's not okay I would suggest moving to accepting objects like [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8vpw). With the objects, it works perfectly. Let me know if any of these work for you so I can write an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Hey, thanks for the solution. Yeah, I can see it's definitely working in the playground and I've seen that pattern a lot when working with advanced types so I'm looking forward to hearing the explanation from you for this. In my real project, I finally decided to use `any` since my interface is really large and this seems abusing the compiler that everything is just so slow and I can't really work with that.

Comment: I was hoping that your use case is not that huge, I will take a look to see if there is a way to optimize

Comment: Thanks for that, but rather than really make my use case work, I'd more like to learn this pattern for future use, because the type system in the project is not that good. Explaining your implementation will actually help me more though.

Comment: Sure, then I will post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[keyof T, keyof Customer, (value: any) => any] | [keyof T, keyof Customer])[]` to type `mappings`, is not what we need since, with this approach you can't tell the type of the `value` in `mapper` and its' return type. Instead, we have to create all possible combinations of `keyof T` and `keyof Customer`, which will resolve in a very pricy type with the complexity of `n*m`, where `n` is the number of keys in `T` and `m` is the number of keys in `Customer`. However, with small-sized or medium-sized types it would be fine.

We will need to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) for our type.

Logic:

- Map through the keys of `T`
- For each of the keys of `T` map through all the keys of `Customer`
- Create a tuple with a specific key of `T`, a specific key of `Customer`, and an optional `mapper` function.

Implementation:

```
type Mappings<Type, FixedType> = {
  [K in keyof Type]: {
    [P in keyof FixedType]: [
      payloadKey: K,
      customerKey: P,
      mapper?: (value: Type[K]) => FixedType[P],
    ];
  }[keyof FixedType];
}[keyof Type];
```

Usage:

```
const createMutateData =
  <T extends Record<string, any>>(
    customerData: Customer,
    mappings: Mappings<T, Customer>[],
  ) => {...}
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nn86kW)

Note: Even though the types are fully correct, due to the compiler's limitation the type of the value in the `mapper` will be `any`, however, the compiler will complain if the wrong type is assigned manually.

This issue only happens with tuples and can be fixed by switching to objects instead of the tuples, with the same keys (`payloadKey`, `customerKey`, `mapper`).

We will slightly change the type that we used for mappings to return object instead of a tuple:

```
type Mappings<Type, FixedType> = {
  [K in keyof Type]: {
    [P in keyof FixedType]: {
      payloadKey: K;
      customerKey: P;
      mapper?: (value: Type[K]) => FixedType[P];
    };
  }[keyof FixedType];
}[keyof Type];
```

The usage of the type remains the same, however, the implementation of the function will have to be changed (done in the playground)

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8vpw)

Comment: Appreciate the effort. A small question, is `[keyof FixedType]` and `[keyof Type]` used for letting the mapped type return its value (the tuple we need here)?

Comment: They are needed because we are using objects. Without `[keyof FixedType]` `{payloadKey: K;customerKey: P;mapper?: (value: Type[K]) => FixedType[P];}` would result in us an object; however, we need the values of that object and by adding `[keyof FixedType]` we get the unions of possible value. The same goes with `[keyof Type]`